# Using .load() with fadeIn() to replace content

Tags: jquery, ajax, replace, fadein, fadeout

Alright I have tried a few different approaches none of witch I'm gratified with so I came to ask.

I've got a wonderful side navigation that I created for one web page. I've tried to make the #content of the page replace with another when a link of the navigation is clicked, I want to make a smooth replacement effect ajax-alike.

I am fairly new to Javascript but found the .replaceWith() thing. Now, I made various manoeuvres with the source but just couldn't make it work. What I tried is using .click() execute .replaceWith() and make it do the replacement by fadeOut() the current content and fadeIn() the new one.

In one of the codes that I wrote it did successfully replace the content by fading but when a user clicked a second time on the navigation link the content would be doubled and tripled..

What's the best way to make a smooth #content-replacing fade in-out effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fade out a div with content A, and Fade In the same div with content B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289250/fade-out-a-div-with-content-a-and-fade-in-the-same-div-with-content-b)

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide it first, otherwise `fadeIn` won't have any effect.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/XmZNc/).

In your case, you probably need to use the jQuery [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method to load contents of different pages.