# jquery ajax success fade effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fadein

I would like to do some effects like `fadeIn` to page once I get the ajax response.
I tried this,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: actionLink,
        cache: false,
        data: ....someData....,
        success: function(data) {
           $(".response").fadeOut(100);
           $(".response").html(data);
           $(".response").fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
```

This is working but data is displayed first and with a flash of 500ms getting data with fade effect but I need to get the loaded data directly with fade effect.

I even tried with [Fade out a div with content A, and Fade In the same div with content B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289250/fade-out-a-div-with-content-a-and-fade-in-the-same-div-with-content-b), but I still get the same issue.

I also tried:

```
$(".response").fadeOut(100).hide();
$(".response").show().html(data).fadeIn(500);
```

Still the same. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This thing worked.........

```
jQuery(".response").fadeOut( 100 , function() {
    jQuery(this).html( data);
}).fadeIn( 1000 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$(".response").fadeOut(100).html(data).fadeIn(500)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Tried it. Still getting the same. First Data is displayed and started fadeIn

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was to set the initial fadeOut() to '0'. This worked perfectly:

```
$(".response").fadeOut(0).html(result).fadeIn(500);
```

As setting an initial fadeOut() with an actual value makes it 'pop' in, and then it fades in. Still not the desirable result.

So by setting the initial fadeOut to 0, means it doesn't spend a tenth of a second fading out before fading in. So you don't get a strange effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(".response").fadeOut(100).delay(100).html(data).fadeIn(500)`

This will force the subsequent operations (the addition of the html to your div) to wait until after the fadeOut has completed.

Comment: Hey, The one below I posted the answer. I got it. thanks for the reply. It tried your suggestion. Still getting the same.

Comment: You should check your answer as being the correct answer to the question, so that when people come here to post an answer they SEE that it is already answered.

Comment: I can only check my own answer after 2 days. That's what I got alert when I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(data)
{
   $(".response").fadeOut(600, function ()
       {
          $(".response").html(data)
        });
   $(".response").fadeIn(600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concept is: Once ajax response received, fadeIn the message - wait for some seconds (delay) - fadeOut 
Like this ------ 
$('div.errorul').fadeIn(600).html( 'msg' ).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);