# new to jquery: need help putting fade in/out script together

Tags: jquery

My in initial problem:  I have a table with basic information about clients on the top half of the the screen.  I want to put a div on the bottom half of the screen that will show detailed information about the client when the name is clicked on on the table in the top half.

I found a bunch of great examples on the jquery end of the problem right here in stackoverflow

Here: [Fade out a div with content A, and Fade In the same div with content B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289250/fade-out-a-div-with-content-a-and-fade-in-the-same-div-with-content-b)
And Here: [How to fade out div slowly, update content, and then fade in div slowly, using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879899/how-to-fade-out-div-slowly-update-content-and-then-fade-in-div-slowly-using-jq)

But my problem is how to get it to work for me and I know it's just because I don't understand how jquery works.

Here's something close to what my site looks like now:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Account Number</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><a href="#">Joe Smith</a></td>
<td>3838.3234</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><a href="#">Jane Doe</a></td>
<td>915.70</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
<div id="client_details>
this is where I want the client details to go that will have more information than the table up above
</div>
```

It seems like a really easy thing to do.  I just don't know how to setup the client details information and the links so it fades in the current (clicked) client's info and fades out the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers provide solid guidance, and while it is as simple as simply doing a chained fadeOut.fadeIn, if you want them to fade-in-fade-out at the same time for a nicer effect without any delays and without first waiting for one to fadeout and the other to fade in, you can do what I did in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gLaDq/22/

Comment: That's what I needed.  Not only the code, but a place to play around with it and understand how it works.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you have loads of users, you might want to consider Ajax calls instead though - look up jQuery's GET and take a look at some examples, it's all dead simple and makes both yours and the life of your server easier.

Comment: At the top of the script I have the current set of clients loaded into an array (clients are loaded based on who logs in) so I'm just doing 1 db call.  But I might look into that if I want to give people the ability to view everyone (600+ clients).  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any jQuery at all?

The basics of what you want to do would look something like this:

```
$('#elementId').fadeOut().html('[NEW MARKUP]').fadeIn();
```

Comment: While I get that concept, how can I make the [NEW MARKUP] section display the correct information for 200+ clients?  Do I set up a div for each client with the detail information and the div's display set to none?  How do I get the link to specify that client's detail information?

Comment: @mikepreble Use ajax calls to do that. Read the documentation for jQuery's GET - this lets you retrieve fragments of the information on demand. Loads of tiny requests is always better than one huge memory hogging display:none intensive display.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to add ids or class to your links.
I.E:

```
<a href="#" id="jane_doe" class="client">Jane Doe</a>
```

Then, with jQuery:

```
   $('.client').click(function(){
//When you click on a link which has the 'client' class...

$('#client_details').fadeOut(100).html('the client details information').fadeIn(100);
});
```

If you need to load the client info, have a look on Ajax ($.post(), $.load())